# Can you copy over macbook screen color calibration profiles? Spyder3Pro

Tags: colors, designer, lcd, calibration

I've bought an 11" and a 13" macbook air and borrowing a spyder3pro from my friend to calibrate the screens. I am trying out the macbook air's and returning one.

I'd like to calibrate both the screens and then also my home external lcd screen and my work external lcd screen.

Can i calibrate these external screens using 1 laptop and the spyder3pro and then copy over the profiles to the other macbook air? Does this work?

I don't really want to calibrate 1 day at work when i have the 13" and then again when i have the 11" with me.

Answer (score 2):

It should be ok since the 11" and 13" have the same gpu... and probably the same display circuitry. It would still be optimal to calibrate each combination of pc/laptop/lcd to get the best possible results. Just copy the icc profile from the correct folder, and copy to the correct destination on the target pc : [ICC Profile Locations](http://www.drycreekphoto.com/Learn/profile_install.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the calibration on both machines, since there can be differences from chip to chip. Also remember that you're going to want to calibrate both machines on both screens, so you'll need four calibrations total. Unless, that is, you're going to try to calibrate your macbook screens as well, for some reason...